# Contradiction Between Multiple Left Joins

Tags: sql, left-join

I am trying to understand the following query which is automatically produced by some software library:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `teacher` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `rel` AS `rel_profile` 
    ON `rel_profile`.`field_id` = 2319 AND `rel_profile`.`item_id` = `t`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `teacher_info` AS `profile` 
    ON `profile`.`id` = `rel_profile`.`related_item_id` 
LEFT JOIN `rel` AS `rel_profile_city` 
    ON `rel_profile_city`.`field_id` = 2320 AND `rel_profile_city`.`item_id` = `profile`.`id` WHERE `rel_profile_city`.`item_id` = 1
```

There are three left joins. I understand the first and second one. What I don't understand is the third left join:

```
LEFT JOIN `rel` AS `rel_profile_city` 
    ON `rel_profile_city`.`field_id` = 2320 AND `rel_profile_city`.`item_id` = `profile`.`id` WHERE `rel_profile_city`.`item_id` = 1
```

The table `rel` has already been used in the first left join:

```
LEFT JOIN `rel` AS `rel_profile` 
    ON `rel_profile`.`field_id` = 2319
```

Now, the same table is left joined again but this time the value of the joined field is different:

```
LEFT JOIN `rel` AS `rel_profile_city` 
    ON `rel_profile_city`.`field_id` = 2320
```

How come that these two joins do not contradict?

Comment: You've joined two _different_ copies of the same table under different aliases - it's not trying to join one copy of the table in two different ways if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The third left join actually becomes a hard join due to the "where" criteria since it limits the resultset to records with a "1" for the 'item_id' of this table. Anyways, it is pulling in property information for the 'related_item_id' associated to the top level teacher record so 't'(teacher) contains your base resultset, 'rel_profile'(rel) contains the profile property information, 'profile'(teacher_info) extends the property information if a 'related_item_id' value exists in the 'rel_profile' column and 'rel_profile_city' is the property information for the related information if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

The query is using aliases:

```
`rel` AS `rel_profile`
```

Says to pretend that the table `rel` is actually a table called `rel_profile`. That alias is then used throughout the rest of the query. I'm not sure of MySQL, but on some other database systems, it's an error to refer to the table as `rel` from then onwards(*) (unless there's another join that re-introduces the table and doesn't provide an alias).

And joining to the same table multiple times is allowed - provided that the names (or aliases) are unique. This is useful when you're trying to construct a result that relies on the content of *multiple* rows from the same table, where the result should occupy a single row.

---

(*) "Then onwards" being in the order in which the clauses are processed, not the text order. E.g. you should use the alias in the `SELECT` clause because, even though it occurs earlier textually, it's (conceptually) processed after the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This query will show `teacher` rows that have associated rows in `rel` with `field_id = 2319` **OR** `field_id = 2320`

Answer (score 1):

The are not "contradicting" each other. Imagine you have a table of users, wich have the demographic and personal data of your users. And another table with the "relation" between users. So, in this "relations" table, you have columns `UserId1` and `UserId2`. If you want a query that returns the data of those two users, you'll need to do two `JOINS` with the table `Users`, once per each `User` column. This doesn't mean that they are contradicting each other.